# Multiline mat tab group

Tags: angular, angular-material

So, i have a mat tab group where the tabs can be added dinamically by the user.

```
<mat-tab-group class="main-tab-group mt-2" [selectedIndex]="selectedTab" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let tabIndex = index">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{ tab.title }}
            <i class="material-icons" (click)="removeTab(tabIndex)">close</i>
        </ng-template>
        <div>
            <app-tab-content [tab]="tab"></app-tab-content>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab disabled>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addNewTab()">Add new tab</button>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

the code is working fine but i need to know if there is a way to put the new tabs on a second line when this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with **TotallyNewb** solution there is a problem that inkBar does not follow selected tab vertically, and in some cases also horizontally (e.g. if the content is resized - not the window).

My approach was similar but with some improvements:

**Usage**

```
<mat-tab-group matMultilineTab>...</mat-tab-group>
```

**Implementation**

**1. Define new style globally**

- I could use component style, however that would have other drawbacks.
- I did not use disablePagination, simply because my version was 8.2.3 thus
  I'm hiding the controls instead.

  ```
    .mat-tab-group.mat-tab-multiline {
      .mat-tab-header:first-child {
        .mat-tab-header-pagination {
          display: none;
        }

        .mat-tab-labels {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
      }
    }
  ```

**2. Define directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[matMultilineTab]',
})
export class MatMultilineTabDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @HostBinding('class.mat-tab-multiline') class = true;

  private readonly onDestroy = new Subject();
  private readonly resizeObserver: ResizeObserver;
  private resizeTimeout: number;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private matTabGroup: MatTabGroup
  ) {
    this.matTabGroup.selectedTabChange.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy)
    ).subscribe(() => this.updateInkBarPosition());

    this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      if (this.resizeTimeout)
        clearTimeout(this.resizeTimeout);
      this.resizeTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.updateInkBarPosition(), 100);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resizeObserver.observe(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-tab-header:first-child')
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.resizeObserver && this.resizeObserver.disconnect();

    this.onDestroy.next();
    this.onDestroy.complete();
  }

  private updateInkBarPosition() {
    const headerElement: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '.mat-tab-header:first-child'
    );
    const activeTabElement: HTMLElement = headerElement.querySelector(
      '.mat-tab-label-active'
    );
    const inkBarElement: HTMLElement = headerElement.querySelector('.mat-ink-bar');
    const listElement: HTMLElement = headerElement.querySelector('.mat-tab-list');
    const bottom = listElement.offsetHeight - 
      (activeTabElement.offsetTop + activeTabElement.offsetHeight);

    inkBarElement.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
    inkBarElement.style.left = activeTabElement.offsetLeft + 'px';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat against the material design guidelines, but should be achievable.

1. Set the `disablePagination` to `true` on your `mat-tab-group` - this removes the "navigation" buttons on the sides if the tab labels overflow the available space.
2. Add a custom class to your mat-tab-group, so that you can apply styles easier (i.e. without using ::ng-deep and !important).
3. Add the `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `.your-class .mat-table-labels` selector. This will make the tab-labels wrap instead of overflowing. Note that sadly this have to be in your styles.(s)css.

Working stackblitz example for reference:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ssy8d

Comment: You are my savior!

Comment: In angular 16 the class selector is `.mat-mdc-tab-labels`